# Blazor Local authentication plus Google and microsoft

Tags: authentication, blazor

I'm working on a blazor web assembly, core hosted project.
The users must have a local account to use the website. For that I use default blazor authentication provider with IdentityServer.

I have a calendar page, where users can add and watch some events.
I would like to offer them the possibility to log in their google or microsoft account in order to see their personnal events in the same place.

But the google or microsoft authentication can't replace the local authentication. It must be a secondary option.

I can't find out how to manage this. All exemples I see use the RemoteAuthenticatorView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add external provider authentication to your server project by following steps described in [Facebook, Google, and external provider authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Ok I tried this, work great with google, but it can override the local account for login, and that's what I don't want. I would like to only link to external account after the local account has been created

Comment: You can disable local account login with IdentityServer and local account creation with Identity

Comment: it's not what I want. I want the users keep login with local accounts. And they can link their personnal account (google, microsoft,..) just to see their calendar events

Comment: With Identity you can link an external account  to a local login in the user management page

Comment: In the IdentityServer Login page you can disable external login form, so the user must login with a local account and link its login to externals login.

Comment: Oh yes ok I think I see thanks you. I will try that and hope the webassembly part can find and use the google cookie to obtain the calendar events